# count and alias in queries with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have the query sql:

```
select top 10 NAME, count(*) as Number
from Products as pro
join Orders as ord on ord.ID_PRODUCT = pro.ID
group by NAME
order by Number desc
```

This code needs to be written in Entity Framework.
How to write?

Comment: what have you tried? If you are totally stuck perhaps look at some examples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = dbContext.Products
                      .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
                      .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Number = g.Count()}
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Number)
                      .Take(10)
```

If you are counting the number of Orders per product, then try this

```
var result = dbContext.Orders
                      .GroupBy(o => o.Product.Name)
                      .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Number = g.Count()}
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Number)
                      .Take(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I've not tested this, but it should do what you need

```
var result =     
     (
       from q2 in
       (
         from q1 in
         (
           from p in Products
           join o in orders on p.ID equals o.ID_PRODUCT
           select p.NAME
         )
         group q1 by q1 into grp
         select new{NAME = grp.Key, Number = grp.Count()}
       )
     orderby q2.Number descending
     select q2
     ).Take(10);
```

- you have here the join between orders and products as the inner most query (q1).
- We only care about selecting the name (duplicated for each order) hence the line `select p.NAME`
- This is grouped with the group by statement - and we get select the Key (the thing that is being grouped by - in this case NAME) and the Count of items in that group. This becomes the subquery q2.
- finally we order q2 by the number descending, and use .Take(10) to get the top 10.